# How to pass value from model to jquery function using looping

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Below is my code

```
 @if (Model.attachments != null && Model.attachments.Count > 0)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < Model.attachments.Count; i++)
        {
            @Html.ActionLink(Model.attachments[i].fileName, "Download", new { id = Model.attachments[i].attachmentID })

            <a href='#' onclick="deleteAttch(Model.attachments[i].attachmentID);" >
                <img src="~/Content/images/red-delete-128.png" class="pictureDelete" />
            </a>

                    <br />
        }


    }
```

my script is as below

```
function deleteAttch(attachID) {

    alert(attachID);
    if (confirm("Are you sure want to delete record")) {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

When I click on alert, my function not able to get the `Model.attachments[i].fileName` , if i change `Model.attachments[i].fileName` to any number, this function work fine.

How can I pass the value from my model to the function ?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean _When I click on alert_? Its not clear what your asking. Are you wanting to pass both the `attachmentID` and `fileName` to your `deleteAttch()` function?

Comment: Are you tried to place hidden element and getting data from there? The statement about `Model.attachments[i].fileName` is confusing - sounds you want to pass 2 values but your example shows just one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the model value is inside of a string literal, you need to place an `@` symbol before the embedded value to ensure that it is evaluated. E.g.

```
 @if (Model.attachments != null && Model.attachments.Count > 0)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < Model.attachments.Count; i++)
        {
            @Html.ActionLink(Model.attachments[i].fileName, "Download", new { id = Model.attachments[i].attachmentID })

            <a href='#' onclick="deleteAttch(@Model.attachments[i].attachmentID);" >
                <img src="~/Content/images/red-delete-128.png" class="pictureDelete" />
            </a><br />
        }
    }
```